# how to print content of arraylist in my console

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, arraylist

```
SearchRequest searchRequest =  SearchRequest.of(s -> s.index("products").query(q -> q.multiMatch(
         t -> t .fields("description","name").query(text)))
         );
       SearchResponse searchResponse =  elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest, Product.class);
       List<Hit> hits = searchResponse.hits().hits();
       List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Hit object : hits){
           System.out.print(((Product) object.source()));
           System.out.println(products.toString());
           products.add((Product) object.source()); 
           
           }
   
       return products;
```

i want to print "products" in my console

i had tried :
System.out.println(products.toString());
but it showing me a ref number only @6ae9453[] i want to display the content inside "products"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this is to add a `toString()` method to you `Product` class. If your `Product` has two attributes, `title` and `price` the `toString()` could be something like

```
 public String toString(){ 
   return title=" + getTitle() + ", price=" + getPrice()
 }
```

Many IDEs has support for generating `toString()` methods. See f.x. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-tostring-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.toString(products)` to convert the array contents to a `String`

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

Comment: Also product should implement toString, otherwise it will print hashcode of product objects